# How to creating an immutable object along with a Builder pattern in ObjC?

Tags: objective-c, immutability, builder

What I am struggling with creating an immutable object with a builder pattern in ObjC. Say I have a user object with the following properties:

1. first name
2. last name

To ensure immutability I propose the following code:

```
@protocol User
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *const firstName;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString *const lastName;
@end

@interface User: NSObject<User>
- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)fName withLastName:(NSString *)lName;
@end

@implementation User
@synthesize firstName;
@synthesize lastName;

- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)fName withLastName:(NSString *)lName
{
    NSParameterAssert(fName);
    NSParameterAssert(lName);
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self->firstName = [fName copy];
        self->lastName = [lName copy];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

What I am really struggling with is how to implement a Builder for this immutable object?

Helpful links on Builder:

[The Builder Pattern in ObjC](http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2014/04/08/the-builder-pattern-in-objective-c-foundation/)

[Builder Pattern definiton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link that you posted above uses two objects to implement the builder pattern. A dedicated builder object which is subsequently passed to a `create/build` method returning the object to be built. Here is a completely contrived example of implement a builder pattern with an immutable object.

First let's create an immutable object; the object which will be built by the builder object.

```
@interface Person: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *firstName;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSString *lastName;

@end

@implementation Person

- (instancetype)initWithFirstName:(NSString *)firstName lastName:(NSString *)lastName{

     self = [super init]
     if(!self) return nil;

     _firstName = [firstName copy];
     _lastName = [lastName copy];

     return self;

}

@end
```

Now let's create the builder object.

```
@interface PersonBuilder: NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *firstName; 
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *lastName;

- (Person *)create;

@end

@implementation PersonBuilder

- (Person *)create{

     return [[Person alloc] initWithFirstName:self.firstName lastName:self.lastName];

}

@end
```

Implement the classes

```
PersonBuilder *builder = [PersonBuilder new];
builder.firstName = "John";
builder.lastName = "Doe";

Person *john = [builder create];
```

In Objective-C I don't really see any good reason to implement the builder pattern unless you are trying to avoid a long and confusing constructor signature or if an object simply has two many properties or options such as `NSDateComponent`. The builder pattern essentially allows you to split the initialization of a complex immutable object into multiple simple setter calls. The `create/build` method implemented on the builder also gives you a hook point in which you can verify that the object is being created as you want. I would only use this pattern in rare cases.